# How do I create a profile in Apple Configurator 2?

Tags: certificate, apple-configurator

I'm trying to create a device profile with certificate settings for an iPhone. I have read the [docs on profiles for Apple Configurator 2](http://help.apple.com/configurator/mac/2.0/#/cadbf9e668) but still can't figure out how to create a new / default profile. All the non-Apple documentation seems to be for the old version of Apple Configurator.

All I seem to be able to do in the UI is open a profile file, but I don't have any existing profile files.

**Is there some folder that contains default profiles, or some way to make a profile from scratch?**

Answer (score 1):

This is actually in the menu, just not the toolbar. **File** > **New Profile**

Answer (score -1):

Visit:  [Create Blue Print in Apple Configurator 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TPB244y-tI&ebc=ANyPxKpC_s-3VXmELmKqzfeLwDb_0CXCvWcmnmy334resbHnJxBGnKPGSFwHerzN9BcaSKSetTT-Ip22cEGnJU7fJJV3FohnuA)